# Off Canvas navigation creating white space at bottom of page in mobile only

Tags: html, css

I created and off canvas navigation which works great in desktop, but on mobile devices when the menu slides open there is white space added to the bottom of the page.

An example can be found [here](http://forestcityirsitedev.azurewebsites.net/investor_home_page_template.html).

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can eliminate that white space by simply adding `margin: -40px;` or something like that to the `.fcFooter` class.

```
.fcFooter {
    font-family: 'ff-tisa-web-pro',serif;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #8a8b8c;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /* margin-top: 40px; This line would be replaced by the following */
    margin-top: -40px;
    border: 1px #ededed;
    border-style: solid none none none;
    display: block;
}
```

You can add that css only to mobile devices by a media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fcFooter {
        margin-top: -40px;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this was useful

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick, I even removed the fcFooter div from the markup, no luck :(

Comment: That's strange, I tested it with the Mozilla Inspector and worked. Are you sure it's not a caché problem? Perhaps something is overwriting the code.

Comment: Oh just to give you an example on an IPhone 5 see <a href="http://forestcityirsitedev.azurewebsites.net/OffCanvasNavIssue.png">this</a>.

Comment: Whoops URL is: http://forestcityirsitedev.azurewebsites.net/OffCanvasNavIssue.png

Comment: Oh, I see. It surely has something to do with some media query, check it with the Mozilla Inspector.

Comment: Mozilla looks good. My feeling also this is a media query issue, but I cannot figure out where. It is driving me nuts :) lol Thanks for your help thus far, checking down the list of stuff to go through.

Answer (score 0):

The height and width of the canvas must be declared in the height and width attributes, if you want it work correctly

Wrong:

```
<canvas style="height: x; width: y;">
```

Correct:

```
<canvas height="x" width="y">
```